# android: error with time picker listener in dynamic edit text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, timepicker

Error messages:

There are two problems and one of them is causing the time picker not to run and the app to crash when I click on the field of the edit text which runs the time picker when clicked on.

1. The 'v' in v.setText... gets an error: 'The method setText(String) is undefined for the type View'. I added a cast like this: '((EditText) v).setText...' and there wasn't an error with it anymore but it is still not working
2. The error message I get when I put 'this' in the time picker dialog listener is: The constructor TimePickerDialog(new View.OnClickListener(){}, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){}, int, int, boolean) is undefined

   editTextTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onClick(final View v) {


           final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
           mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
           mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


           TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(**this**,//same Activity Context like before
                   new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                       @Override
                       public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                               int minute) {


                           ((EditText) v).setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute); //You set the time for the EditText created
                       }



                   }, mHour, mMinute, true);
           tpd.show();



       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this** refers to anonymous class implementing OnClickListener. To get reference to Context (Activity) you need to provide

```
Activity.this
```

Comment: Thanks, just figured that out before seeing your comment. It works now.